# Show $(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial \ln V})_{T} = \frac{V}{p}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

**Question:**

In thermodynamics, the pressure of a system, $p$, can be considered as a function of the variables $V$ (volume) and $T$ (temperature) or as a function of the variables $V$ and $S$ (entropy).

(i) By expressing $p(V,S)$ in the form $p(V,S(V,T))$ evaluate $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T} - (\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{S}$ in terms of $(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{T}$ and $(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_{V}$.

(ii) Hence, using $TdS = dU + pdV$ (conservation of energy with $U$ the internal energy), show that:

$(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial \ln V})_{T} - (\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial \ln V})_{S} = (\frac{\partial (pV)}{\partial T})_{V} [ \frac{p^{-1}(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T}+1}{(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T})_{V}}]$.

[Hint: $(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial \ln V})_{T} = \frac{V}{p}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T}$]

(This question is from http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/A3a.pdf .)

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**My Attempt:**

(i) By Chain Rule:

$dp = (\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{S}dV + (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V}dS$

=>$(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T} - (\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{S} = (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V} (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{T} = \frac{(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{T}}{(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_{V}}$ (by reciprocal rule)

---

(ii) $TdS = dU + pdV$

=> $T (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{T} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} + p$ and $T (\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_{V} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}$

So $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T} - (\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{S} = p [\frac{(p^{-1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} + 1}{(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}}]$

Then observe

$dS = (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{T}dV + (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_{V}dT $

So

$dp = [(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{S} + (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V}(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_{T}]dV + (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V}(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_{V}dT$

=> $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial U})_{V} = (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V} (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_{V} (\frac{\partial T}{\partial U})_{V}$

Then by Chain Rule (using our expression for $dS$)

$(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_{V} = (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_{V} (\frac{\partial T}{\partial p})_{V}$ => $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T})_{V} = (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V}(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_{V}$

And so (using the results above and the Reciprocal Rule):

$(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T} - (\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{S} = p [\frac{p^{-1}(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} + 1}{(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_{V}}] =  p (\frac{\partial p}{\partial U})_{V} [{p^{-1}(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} + 1}] = p (\frac{\partial p}{\partial S})_{V} (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_{V} (\frac{\partial T}{\partial U})_{V} [{p^{-1}(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} + 1}] = p (\frac{\partial p}{\partial T})_{V} [\frac{ {p^{-1}(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{T} + 1}}{(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T})_{V}}]$

(This is where I am stuck)

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Comments:**

The issue I have with the question (I assume) is that I am unable to derive the expression in the hint, i.e. showing that $(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial \ln V})_{T} = \frac{V}{p}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{T}$.

I would assume that a very similar expression exists when keeping $S$ constant.

Comment: If you mean $\ln p$, you write it as $\verb+\ln p+$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly, you are wondering how to derive the hint, yes?

Comment: @Cocomos yes I am wondering how to derive the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial \ln V}\right)_T=
\left(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial V}\right)_T
\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial \ln V}\right)_T=
\frac{\left(\frac{\partial \ln p}{\partial V}\right)_T}{
\left(\frac{\partial \ln V}{\partial V}\right)_T}=\frac{\frac{1}{p}\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_T}{\frac{1}{V}}=\frac{V}{p}\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_T
$$
The first equality is chain rule. The second is reciprocal. The third in numerator is chain rule. In general $(\ln x)'=1/x$. The last equality is just rearrangement.